# List comprehension vs List.concat

Tags: performance, f#

I have following function in my (turn-based) game code, which lists all legal moves for a player in a game:

```
let moves game = 
    let movesType1 game = ... //returns Move list
    let movesType2 game = ... //returns Move list
    let movesType3 game = ... //returns Move list

    List.concat [ (movesType1 game); (movesType2 game); (movesType3 game) ]
```

Now I'm wondering what would be the difference if I used list comprehension and `yield!` to do following:

```
let moves game = 
    let movesType1 game = ... //returns Move list
    let movesType2 game = ... //returns Move list
    let movesType3 game = ... //returns Move list

    [ yield! movesType1 game
      yield! movesType2 game
      yield! movesType3 game ]
```

I might use this function many times in some cases, so I'm a little concerned about performance.

Comment: You should use sequences rather than lists.

Comment: Rather than asking, why not measure each one for yourself?  You can use `#time` in F# Interactive to perform basic timing.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple test script measuring the timing difference between your two implementations:

```
let test1 () = List.concat [ [1..10000]; [1..10000]; [1..10000] ]

let test2 () = [ yield! [1..10000]
                 yield! [1..10000]
                 yield! [1..10000] ]

let runTest testImplementation = 
    for i in 1..1000 do
        testImplementation () |> ignore
#time
runTest test1 //Real: 00:00:02.353, CPU: 00:00:02.371, GC gen0: 143, gen1: 96, gen2: 1
#time
System.GC.WaitForFullGCComplete() |> ignore
#time
runTest test2 //Real: 00:00:03.739, CPU: 00:00:03.712, GC gen0: 185, gen1: 185, gen2: 0
#time
```

It appears `List.concat` is a bit better, but like all performance things, you should measure to see if the performance benefit actually matters to your use case.